# Operator >> overload with struct?

Tags: c++, overloading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [overload operator<< within a class in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200475/overload-operator-within-a-class-in-c)
>   [Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

Is there any way this is possible?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct test{
  int n;
};
int main(){
  test t1;
  cin >> t1;
  return 0;
}
```

For all I know, it is not possible, but I had an exam yesterday and that question came in it, it asked me to write the functions missing.

Comment: It is possible. I don't know the exact way, though.

Comment: I duped for http://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719/962089. Input/Output is right near the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the include:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

You should include both namespaces:
using namespace System;  // ie System::Console
using namespace std;

You'll need to use:

```
std::cin >> t1.n;
```

Comment: a) The OP was supposed to write missing functions. It's very possible to overload `operator>>` to do that. b) `using namespace System;`? This is C++... Other than that, `<c*>` is preferred over `<*.h>`, and `using namespace std;` is a bit overrated.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, structs are the same as classes. So yes, you can do the same thing as you do with classes.